# Where can I find the Eclipse .eea external annotation files?

Tags: java, eclipse, annotations, eclipse-jdt

I'm trying to update our build configuration that was originally setup by somebody else.
It uses the Eclipse external annotations - specified in a directory of .eea files.
The ones were have were obviously for Java 8, as the directory is named "JRE18-eclipse-external-annotations"

Where can I find updated ones for Java 11?  My searches have all come up empty.

Comment: JRE18 could equally be the current Java 18

Comment: Since this was setup several years ago, highly unlikely.